# Ancestry Ethnicity says I'm 100% Irish and Scottish?

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, ethnicity

Can you explain how I can be 100% Ireland and Scotland in my Ethnicity estimate on Ancestry?

Why not 99% Ireland and 1% Scotland, how can it be 100% both?

Comment: It's 100% a mixture of Irish and Scottish, not 100% both.

Comment: Of course I understand that you can't be 100%  both.... I would just like a breakdown of each...On other profiles you see smaller percentages, say 98%Irish, 1%Scottish, 1% Italian!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Ancestry and other companies compare your results with groups of people who are living today in various places, groups called *reference populations*.  They choose people whose families have lived in the same place for a certain amount of time.

Do keep in mind that all these estimates are only that: **estimates**. I highly recommend the entire series of blog posts that Judy G. Russell has written on the topic, including ["Still Not Soup"](https://www.legalgenealogist.com/2017/04/16/still-not-soup/).

For detailed information on how Ancestry arrives at its ethnicity estimates, read their [white paper](https://www.ancestrycdn.com/dna/static/images/ethnicity/help/WhitePaper_Final_091118dbs.pdf) which is available from the Ancestry Support Website.

Other AncestryDNA White Papers are also available. See the support topic [AncestryDNA® White Papers](https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/AncestryDNA-White-Papers).